# Does Heroku automatically cache Rails controller actions by default?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, heroku

I'm seriously dubmfounded.  I have a Rails application that stores blog posts in an Article model. The index page calls a scope on the model and returns the latest articles.  However when I load the page, only some of the articles are showing up, but when I copy the code over to the Heroku console the missing articles show up in the results.

Here's the index action:

```
def index
    @articles = Article.featured_published_articles.order("date_time DESC").page(params[:page])
end
```

Here's the scope:

```
scope :featured_published_articles , where("featured = ? AND status IN (?) AND date_time <= ?", true , ['published','published-pending'], DateTime.now)
```

The method works properly when I call it from the console, but when I load the page, not all the results are showing up.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not heroku specific, but the scope is storing the "DateTime.now" when it's first interpreted. Basically, the DateTime.now is when you push to heroku, not "now".

You want to use a lambda here instead

```
scope :featured_published_articles , -> {where("featured = ? AND status IN (?) AND date_time <= ?", true , ['published','published-pending'], DateTime.now) }
```

in Rails4, this won't be a problem (it'll give you a load error), but in Rails3 it'll load and cause the problems you are seeing.